# Excel VBA AutoFit runs slowly

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel vba macro that creates and formats a sales quote. I have a function that autofits merged cells. I use this function to autofit description fields as some of them are long and some are short. On a typical quote, this function is called around 40 times. The macro completes in under a second. If I run the exact same macro again (perhaps with different settings on how it will display) it takes upwards of 30-60 seconds. There's nothing in the rest of the macro that slows down with each run except for the following block:

Is there something that could be making this code run slower for the exact same set of inputs?

```
Sub AutoFit_Height(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MergeWidth As Single
Dim cM As Range
Dim CWidth As Double
Dim NewRowHt As Double

With Target
    .MergeCells = False
    CWidth = .Cells(1).ColumnWidth
    MergeWidth = 0
    For Each cM In Target
        cM.WrapText = True
        MergeWidth = cM.ColumnWidth + MergeWidth
    Next
    'small adjustment to temporary width
    MergeWidth = MergeWidth + Target.Cells.count * 0.66
    .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = MergeWidth
    .EntireRow.AutoFit
    NewRowHt = .RowHeight
    .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = CWidth
    .MergeCells = True
    .RowHeight = NewRowHt
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the start of the main body of code (the one that calls this subroutine) and add

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

as one of the first lines.  Then at the end of that function, after this subroutine has been called, turn it back on:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This will keep it from redrawing the screen for every change in column/row size, resulting in a significantly faster run time.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, I start the function with that already. As well as suppressing calculations, events, and alerts.

Answer (score 0):

Optimazing your script might start with

- **using xlsb file saving extension**
- **look for any unecessary formatting by deleting unused rows and
  columns and saving so to make the vertical and horizontal scroll bar
  scroll just to the necessary data**
- **Use named range as much as possible**

This could be added to your script

At the start of the main module from where you call other modules or functions

```
With Application
.DisplayAlerts = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
.EnableEvents = False
End With
```

At the end of the main module task is complete

```
With Application
.DisplayAlerts = True
.ScreenUpdating = True
.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
.EnableEvents = True
End With
```

As you are manipulating many worksheet objects that's quite a cpu intensive process. A change in algorithm could improve time needed for this process. Maybe you should post the entire code so to help you further.

Cheers,

Pascal

http://multiskillz.tekcities.com

Answer (score 0):

Autofit is painfully slow for me to. The only thing I can add to any other answer here is to put it in a separate module and only call it when necessary or time is available. Also, to implement last, once all other code is tested and working.